# Different UI behaviour for iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Recently, I uploaded my application to Apple store from XCode 4.x with OS 10.7. After that I upgraded my machine with Xcode 5.0 to start with iOS 7. Now I downloaded my application from the Apple' store to iPhone 4S with iOS 7 installed. I see application's UI on device is totally different from the iOS 7 simulator. On device navigation and Tab bar are old fashioned like iOS 6 while I am expecting like iOS 7.

I think the reason behind this that the application has been uploaded from XCode 4.x and when I will upload it from Xcode 5 it will show the latest UI of iOS7.

Do anyone facing the same problem? Do you think Apple should do it itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand it right. Applications must build and updated on xCode 5 for showing the new iOS design.

You must check your app on xCode 5 before uploading it as "iOS7 ready", Note that your app might work fine with the old design on iOS 6 but no one can check that for you as they might be UI problems and even crashes depending on your old UI and code.

If you are using 100% iOS native interface you should not have to much work.

Answer (score 0):

You are app is built on iOS 6 SDK, To use iOS 7 UI features, build your app using iOS 7 SDK. iOS 7SDK will be available with xCode 5. SO upgrade to xCode 5 and build app against base SDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 doesn't exists ;)

Your problem is that you compiled your app with Xcode 4. Only Xcode 5 is embedding iOS 7 SDK. If you want to solve your problem you have to submit your app again but compiled with Xcode 5.

(don't forget to set your correct deployment target)